# How do CEOs of some companies have time to be board members of others?

Tags: time-management

I've noticed in many big corporations that the CEOs or people with executive board member positions also have jobs of high positions elsewhere. How is this possible if those positions are so demanding? Is it because these positions require the person to make the big decisions (without having to go through hours of research or planning, since that would be done by their employees) and aren't actually too demanding in time?

Comment: They'll make the time because the board gets to decide how much the CEO makes. They need to scratch each other's backs as they ensure the board votes all the CEOs exorbitant salaries with golden parachute retirement packages. Would you make the time if it meant millions to hundreds of millions in compensation difference? It is also a way of networking, after all $100 million from company A isn't as good as getting another $100 million from company B after you leave company A.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about navigating the workplace.

Comment: Plus a big part of a CEOs job is to network to get more business and being a borad member can help with that greatly.

Comment: CEOs are mainly actors, there to reassure investors and shareholders. Notice that most CEOs of large companies look and act virtually identical, and compare them with entrepreneurs who actually started their businesses. Thats why they have time to do other things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Board members only have official functions of the company during board meetings. That is not to say the board members never do work on behalf of the company at any other time just that their official duties are limited to the board meetings.

The day to day activities are handled by the CEO and their management cadre. Usually CEO's will not have positions in other companies unless there is a subsidiary relationship. For instance the CIO of the parent might also be the CEO of the subsidiary IT Company, and the CFO could be the CEO of the financial company. These duties over lap anyway so it may not really impact their workload.

One thing to note about Senior executive positions is that they are rarely 9-5 jobs.  They often start before 6am and just as often end after 10pm. Many of their duties completed out of the office, making deals, handling emergency phone calls, and dealing with the various needs of the business.  This is all on top of the paper work required by regulations, meetings, strategy sessions, and just the process of doing business that is often more than a full time job by itself.